# Only return Models for specific Manufacturer on Equipment

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I have three tables:

```
1) Manufacturer
2) Model
3) Vehicle
```

The Manufacturer table extract:

```
Manufacturer
BMW
Merc
Toyota
```

The Model table extract:

```
Manufacturer Model
BMW          330
BMW          325
BMW          340
Merc         A200
Merc         C350
Toyota       Land Cruiser
Toyota       Tundra
```

The Vehicle table

```
VehicleNo  Manufacturer  Model
1          Toyota        Only Tundra or Land Cruiser
2
3
4
5
```

The solution is in MS Access so there are no forms. The following selections are made directly on the vehicle table. The user chooses the Manufacturer from the Manufacturer table and the model from the model table on the Vehicle table. Problem is that I want to limit the possible selections of model to the Manufacturer that has already been chosen for that line item. That is, if Toyota has been chosen as Manufacturer, only land Cruiser and Tundra can be chosen as Models.

The query currently returns all of the models as possible selections across the manufacturers that have been selected per vehicle. Current example: If BMW and Merc have been chosen as Manufacturers on Vehicle, then all BMW and Merc models are available for selection in the Model field.

Current Query:

```
    SELECT Model.[Model]
    FROM Manufacturer 
    INNER JOIN (Model INNER JOIN VEHICLE ON (Model.[Model] = VEHICLE.Model) 
    AND (Model.Manufacturer = VEHICLE.Manufacturer)) 
    ON (Manufacturer.Manufacturer = Model.Manufacturer) 
    AND (Manufacturer.Manufacturer = VEHICLE.Manufacturer)
    WHERE (((VEHICLE.Model)=[Model].[Model]))
    ORDER BY VEHICLE.Model;
```

Comment: You say "The user chooses...", yet your SQL shows no user input. Therefore I am going to assume you have a form that has at least two comboboxes or listboxes to show Manufacturer and Model tables? If so, then you want to filter the 2nd combobox based on the user selection in the 1st combobox.  If you are doing something else, then you need to add detail about how the user is interfacing with your code.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But I'm using MS access and the user will make selections directly on the table, not in a form. So hence the need for the join

Comment: I am unaware of any built-in interface in Access that will let you click on a row in a table and have a filter applied simply because you clicked on it... and certainly not to apply a second filter for a linked table.  You can create your query, run it, then have the user click the drop-down in the column header and apply a filter. But from there they would have to keep applying filters on the next column desired.  This would be so easy (and happier users) if you used a form.

Comment: You shouldn't ever let users loose directly in tables. Make a form and this all becomes easy. It's what Forms are designed to do. Tables store data. Forms provide interaction and views on that data.

Comment: Make your data form into a datasheet - it looks just like a table to the users - but you can then use combo boxes to filter based on your other fields.